# Gap At The Top Of Basic Webpage?

Tags: html, css

I've setup a simple webpage, and there is a weird gap at the top which I don't know how to fix. Other sites I've developed haven't had this issue at all..?

Here's my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<title>sitename</title>
<link rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css" href="main.css">
</head>

<body>
<div id="wrapper">      
    lorem ipsum
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And the CSS:

```
body {
background-color:#323232;
}

#wrapper {
width:960px;
margin:0pt auto;
background-color:#272727;
}
```

And here's a pic of the weird gap:

[image: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/46018476/TEMP/gap.png]

Is this just my version of FireFox acting up temporarily or am I doing something obviously wrong?

Comment: Possibly useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/116754/best-css-reset

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think by default browsers do tend to add margin or padding to either the `<html>` or `<body>` element, I can never remember which.

**Edit:** as per other answers and comments (e.g. [Rahool’s](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8848483/20578)), looks like it’s `margin` on `<body>`.

So this should sort out your issue:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Because the body tag default margin, and you need to reset it, such as:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For every page, each web browser uses a set of default styles **before** any other css styles are applied.

[Mozilla default style sheet](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla/source/layout/style/html.css)

[Internet Explorer User Agent Style Sheets](http://www.iecss.com/)

You will need to reset the styles applied by these default css.

*Firefox applies default 8px margin to body element. To reset it,*

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding

```
*{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```